# testng-results.xml file getting overridden when running tests in parallel

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng, testng.xml

When running tests in parallel using TestNg, the reports, emailable and testng-results.xml seems to be getting overridden and show results from the last thread only and not combined of all the threads.

Sample testng.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="Smoke Suite" parallel="tests" thread-count="2">

<groups>
    <run>
        <include name="Smoke"/>
    </run>
</groups>

<test name="1">
    <classes>
        <class name="one">
            <parameter name="executionId" value="UIXTC-"/>
        </class>
    </classes>
</test>

<test name="2">
    <classes>
        <class name="two">
            <parameter name="executionId" value="UIXTC-"/>
        </class>
    </classes>
</test>
</suite>
```

surefire details

```
    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
            <configuration>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>src/com/blueoptima/${MODULE}/suiteXmls/${SUITE}Suite.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
                <threadCount>${THREADS}</threadCount>
                <environmentVariables>
                    <PROPERTIES_FILE>${PROPERTIES_FILE}</PROPERTIES_FILE>
                </environmentVariables>
            </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

The emailable and testng-results xml show results of the test methods from test name "2" only, even though the testng-results.xml is able to read all test names.

Sample testng-results.xml output file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testng-results ignored="21" total="22" passed="1" failed="0" skipped="0">
<reporter-output>
</reporter-output>
<suite started-at="2021-01-28T18:06:49 IST" name="Smoke Suite" finished-at="2021-01-28T18:10:40 IST" 
duration-ms="230568">
<groups>
  <group name="sanity">
    <method signature="method 2" name="method 2" class="Class 2"/>
    <method signature="method 3" name="method 3" class="Class 3"/>
  </group> <!-- sanity -->
  <group name="Smoke">
    <method signature="method 1" name="method 1" class="Class 1"/>
    <method signature="method 2" name="method 2" class="Class 2"/>
    <method signature="method 3" name="method 3" class="Class 3"/>
  </group> <!-- Smoke -->
</groups>

<test-method signature="method 1" started-at="2021-01-28T18:09:24 IST" name="method 1" data- 
provider="dataProviderForTest" finished-at="2021-01-28T18:10:32 IST" duration-ms="67731" 
status="PASS">
      <params>
        <param index="0">
          <value>
            <![CDATA[{testCaseId=UIXTC-}]]>
          </value>
        </param>
      </params>
      <reporter-output>
      </reporter-output>
    </test-method>
```

As it can be seen, it is able to identify all 3 methods in smoke suite, but shows results for only 1 method.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround to this issue , you can add junit listener (which captures all threads) in your testng xml  as below

```
<suite name = "Sample Tests">
<listeners>
    <listener class-name="org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter"/>
</listeners>
```

and convert the junit xml reports to a summarized html using the simple command line utility [prettyjunit](https://pypi.org/project/prettyjunit/).